# Timer Interval Overflow visual basic

Tags: vb.net, vba, timer

i'm trying to use `Timer`,it works well i'm using it with other variables

```
 Const daily As Integer = 86400000
 Const weekly As Integer = 604800000
 Const hour As Integer = 3600000
```

but i get overflow error when using monthly variable `Private monthly As Long` here's my code

```
Private timepick As New DateTimePicker()
Private timeLeft As Long
Public trackTimer As Long
Private CloseAllowed As Boolean
Private time As ULong
Private progress As Long
Const daily As Integer = 86400000
Const weekly As Integer = 604800000
Const hour As Integer = 3600000
Private monthly As Long
Private currentDate As Date = DateTime.Now
Private controller As Boolean = False

Private Sub AutoShutDown_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AutoShutDown.Tick
    If (controller = False) Then
        AutoShutDown.Enabled = False
    Else
        CountDown.Enabled = True
        progress = 0
        WarningForm.Timer1.Enabled = True
        timeLeft = time
        trackTimer = timeLeft
        AutoShutDown.Interval = time 'Overflow 
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = timeLeft
    End If
    'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "-s -t 00")
    MsgBox("Shuting down...")
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    timepick.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time
    timepick.ShowUpDown = True
    timepick.Location = New Point(154, 12)
    timepick.Width = 123
    Me.Controls.Add(timepick)
    cmbAction.SelectedIndex = 0
    rdoOnce.Checked = True
    Dim days As Long = DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month)
    monthly = (days * daily)
End Sub
```

part of my `Select Case`

```
   Case "Monthly"
            Dim dueDate As Date = DateTime.Parse(currentDate.Month & "/" & cmbControl.Text & "/" & currentDate.Year & " " & timepick.Text)
            Dim dayOfTheMonth As Integer = ((dueDate.Day * 24 - currentDate.Hour) * hour) + (dueDate.Minute * 60000) + (dueDate.Hour * hour)
            Dim currentDayOfTheMon As Integer = ((currentDate.Day * 24 - currentDate.Hour) * hour) + (currentDate.Minute * 60000) + (currentDate.Hour * hour)
            If (dayOfTheMonth > currentDayOfTheMon) Then
                timeLeft = (dayOfTheMonth - currentDayOfTheMon)
            End If
            time = monthly
            controller = True
    End Select

    trackTimer = timeLeft
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = timeLeft
    AutoShutDown.Interval = timeLeft
    AutoShutDown.Enabled = True
    CountDown.Enabled = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but i get overflow error when using monthly variable

That is the good kind of problem to have, it tells you that your code is bad.  The Timer's Interval property is an Integer, the unit is milliseconds.  One month is 31 x 24 x 3600 x 1000 = 2,678,400,000 milliseconds.  That's more than Integer.MaxValue, 2,147,483,648.  Or in other words, you can't use Timer to time more than 24 days using milliseconds.

A simple workaround is to not time the entire period but let your timer tick, say, every hour.  Actual interval doesn't matter, just check if enough time passed. Roughly:

```
Private ShutdownDate As DateTime

Private Sub StartShutdownTimer(ByVal interval As Long)
    ShutdownDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(interval)
    AutoShutDown.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub AutoShutDown_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If DateTime.UtcNow >= ShutdownDate Then
        AutoShutDown.Enabled = False
        '' etc...
    End If
End Sub
```